# ActionLink across controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to create an action link within a view for my controller RequestedService which takes the user to another controller and action in the form:

/ItemsForService/Create/{id}

With ItemsForService being the controller that the create function exists in.

So far I have:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Item", "ItemsForService", "Create", New With {.id = currentItem.RequestedServiceId})
```

However this seems to pass it as Create?=id and not Create/id

How would I pass as the latter?

Comment: Can you show us the route in your Global file that relates to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the correct overload of ActionLink to get the intended result

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Item", "ItemsForService", "Create", New With { id = currentItem. currentItem }, Nothing)
```

You don't need the `.id = ...` it's just `id = ...`

The overload is `ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)`

Adding the last parameter of `Nothing` as null HTML attributes is necessary when you supply parameters to the action. Or if you actually needed to apply HTML Attributes to the link, you would use:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Item", "ItemsForService", "Create", New With { id = currentItem. currentItem }, New With { @class = "MyCustomCssClassName" } )
```

Comment: I have added the following  @Html.ActionLink("Add Item", "ItemsForService", "Create", New With {id = currentItem.RequestedServiceId }, null) but am now getting the following 2 errors: Anonymous type member name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments. &'null' is not declared. 'Null' constant is no longer supported; use 'System.DBNull' instead.

Comment: I was using the c# version so instead of Null in VB you probably want Nothing, I'll update it